# Create semi-circular border CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a card look like this, the border or the sides of the card are semi-circular, is it possible to make it with css? if yes, how? Thank you in advance

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  
}

.content-card {
  width: 315px;
  height: 131px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content-card">
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont see any image or code what have you added

Comment: @TohirulIslam ohh sorry, but I just got to this stage only, I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: you much rounded do you need

Comment: as much as the picture shows, i think 10 circle right and left

Comment: the thing is i dont see any pictures 

Comment: you try to use ```border-radius: 50%``` and width and height equal it will create a circle then you will understand how border-radius to decrease.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tohirul/pen/yLEwdpa go here I have created a circle for you using your code

Comment: ahh maybe because the color of the card is white that why, I'll change it first

Comment: I have tried it go to the codepen

Comment: @TohirulIslam i just add the image, sorry that not what i expected in codepen

Comment: edit the codepen expand the width and see if it matches if the it is too much circular decrease the border-radius.

Comment: @TohirulIslam i want to make the sides of the card is semi circular like ticket card not rounded, I have added the image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple background can do it:

```css
.content-card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(8px at left ,#0000 98%,#fff) left ,
   radial-gradient(8px at right,#0000 98%,#fff) right;
  background-size: 50.5% 25px;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
  border-radius: 8px;
}


body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-card">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## The old way - border-image

It permits you to use the willing image for borders, it was widely use for this kind of cases. You can have repeat option on it to allow different box's sizes with the same style.
The mozilla doc is quite explicit with good examples of it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

## The recent way - without image

You have the possibility to use pseudo-element :after and :before and stylize those elements with a repeated background using radial-gradient.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.ticket {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.ticket:before,
.ticket:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 160px;
}
  
.ticket:before {
  left: -5px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, transparent 50%, #FBFBFB 50%, #FBFBFB 100%) -7px -8px/16px 16px repeat-y;
}
  
.ticket:after {
  left: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent, transparent 50%, #FBFBFB 0%, #FBFBFB 100% ) -3px -7px / 16px 16px repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket"></div>
```